# How to set year to 2020 if there is no year set on a VARCHAR date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-format, str-to-date

I'm working with a quite old database... And dates are stored as VARCHAR, and I need to keep dates as VARCHAR :S but expanding it with year=2020, hour=0, minute=0, and second=0 if that fields are not set.

Dates have all kind of weird formats, such as '01/08', '01/08/20', '01/08/2020' and so on. I'm dealing good with all formats, except when year is not set, I have tried with this query, but it set the year to 0 and causes an error with STR_TO_DATE() function

```
UPDATE people
SET date = 
    IF (
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')) > 0 ,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') ,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') + INTERVAL 2020 YEAR, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
    )
```

Any idea dudes?

Comment: How do you know if 01/08/20 means "January 8, 2020", "January 8, 1920", "1 August 2020" or "2001 August 20" etc?

Comment: This is my idea of hell.

Comment: The only solution is to collect all formats which are used and create separate query for each separate format. Then you may combine these queries via UNION or use complex CASE. As @jarlh shows some values may have dual meaning - they must be processed separately too.

Comment: Why are you storing the "corrected" date back into a varchar column? You could simply save it into a new `date` column. Having said that, a simple `case when d regexp ... then ...` should do it.

Comment: I am with Akina here; I'd do this step by step. One format first, then the next. Maybe I'd do this even outside SQL with a programming language. That would be slower, but probably easier to code.

Comment: I'm Spanish, all dates "should be" day/month/year or day/month, that's sure, I keep trying, maybe I will try with C#, extracting data, formatting and then inserting it again for human beings. Thanks for all dudes

Comment: @ThorstenKettner *Maybe I'd do this even outside SQL with a programming language.* I have solved a similar task (normalizing the data matched more than 20 patterns, and with misprints, ~30k values) long ago... using Excel.